# Angular 2: merging one observable "inside" another

Tags: angular, observable, subscribe

On page load I load this data into the template as items:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Leonardo",
    "weapon": "sword",
},
{
    "height": "2",
    "name": "Donatello",
    "weapon": "stick",
},
```

I load the data using this in my component:

```
this.dataSubscription = this.dataService.getAllTurtles().subscribe(res => this.turtles = res);
```

Each item also has a button "LOAD MORE DATA". When I click on it, it loads some extra data that belongs to that specific item:

```
this.dataSubscription = this.dataService.getData(id).subscribe(res => this.singleData = res);
```

Loads me this

```
{
    "favoritePizza": "Hawai",
}
```

Now, I want to merge this data into the original data stream, so I'd have:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Leonardo",
    "weapon": "sword",
    "favoritePizza": "Hawai"
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Donatello",
    "weapon": "stick",
}
```

But I'm unsure how to concat the arrays that way. Currently when I do it with concat:

```
this.dataSubscription = this.dataService.getData(id).subscribe(res => this.turtles = this.turtles.concat(res));
```

I just get concated arrays:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Leonardo",
    "weapon": "sword",
},
{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Donatello",
    "weapon": "stick",
}
{
    "favoritePizza": "Hawai"
}
```

How do I access a specific item inside the array using it's id and add to it data I have loaded later on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
this.dataService.getAdditionalData(id)
  .subscribe(data => {
    this.turtles = this.turtles.map(i => {
      if (i.id !== id) {
        return i;
      }
      return { ...i, ...data };
    })
  })
```

example https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tl4mt1?file=app%2Fapp.component.ts

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

```js
var a1 = [{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Leonardo",
  "weapon": "sword",
  "favoritePizza": "Hawai"
}, {
  "id": "2",
  "name": "Donatello",
  "weapon": "stick",
}]

var a2 = {
  "favoritePizza": "Hawai",
}

a1 = a1.map((e) => {
  return e.id === "1" ? Object.assign(e, a2) : e
})

console.log(a1);
```

There might be better options though!!!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your call done from button "LOAD MORE DATA"

```
this.dataSubscription = this.dataService.getData(id).subscribe(res => this.singleData = res);
```

should be named

```
this.dataSubscription = this.dataService.getTurtle(1).subscribe(res => this.singleData = res);
```

With getTurtle that return an Observable to the Object Turtle, which contain, by design of document into mongoDB, the details of Turtle, including the favorite pizza:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "Leonardo",
  "weapon": "sword",
  "favoritePizza": "Hawai"
}
```

Comment: Can you explain further? Why would the name matter?

Comment: Behind the name, it is the logic. If you search to get he favorite pizza of Leaonardo, I think that the good way to get it is to ask the detail of Turtle "Leonardo". By asking a service that return details of a Turtle (maybe not only the favoritePizza). Moreover, getData is not really readble.

Comment: I see, but what if each turtle has 1mb worth  of info. I really only need this one specific bit of information.

Comment: I understood your requirement of optimization, so why you use map ;-). For debugging purpose, REST service could return the id of the turtle with the favoritePizza.  For optimization purpose, you can 1/ eventually use the 304 status of the service, 2/ If favoritePizza is very light comparing to the 1mb of Turtle you can get it before, without displaying it to the user. To avoid latency of a request to the server.